# Why $response->getBody() of httpClient returns NULL?

Tags: laravel, httpclient

I try to get data from https://climate-api.open-meteo.com service using  Http::get method, but running request
method getBody returns null, not array of data :

```
$response = Http::get('https://climate-api.open-meteo.com/v1/climate', [
'query' => [
'latitude' => $latitude,
'longitude' => $longitude,
'start_date' => $from->format('Y-m-d'),
'end_date' => $to->format('Y-m-d'),
]
]);

// RETURNS TRUE
\Log::info(varDump($response->successful(), ' -10 $response->successful()::'));


// RETURNS 200
\Log::info(varDump($response->getStatusCode(), ' -11 $response->getStatusCode()::'));


// RETURNS NULL
\Log::info(varDump(json_decode($response->getBody(), true), ' -12 $response->getBody()::'));
```

Making sample request like :

```
https://climate-api.open-meteo.com/v1/climate?latitude=40.4165&longitude=-3.7026&start_date=2023-07-09&end_date=2023-07-11&models=CMCC_CM2_VHR4&daily=temperature_2m_max
```

I got valid structure of data and do not see I got invalid data in   $response->getBody() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fault lies in the **Query string** that you provide where you should pass in the following way:

```
$response = Http::get('https://climate-api.open-meteo.com/v1/climate', [
    'latitude'   => '40.4165',
    'longitude'  => '3.7026',
    'start_date' => '2023-07-09',
    'end_date'   => '2023-07-11',
    // 'models'     => 'CMCC_CM2_VHR4',
    // 'daily'      => 'temperature_2m_max'
]);
```

In addition, there is no method called `getBody` but it is called `body` as Laravel illustrated [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#making-requests).